# Toggle a grid by clicking a button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, grid, click

I'm trying to collapse a `Grid` by clicking on a `Button`. This is how my `Button` is represented in xaml:

```
 <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="25" Content="&lt;&lt;" Click="OnClicked" x:Name="btnCollapse"></Button>
```

I want to collapse a `Grid` on clicking this `Button` (something like a docked window) and bring back the `Grid` on clicking on the `Button` again. This is how I do that in the code behind:

```
private bool clicked;
private void OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    clicked             = !clicked;
    //leftPane is my grid
    leftPane.Visibility = clicked ? Visibility.Collapsed:Visibility.Visible;
    btnCollapse.Content = clicked ? ">>" : "<<";
}
```

This works fine, my question is how can I represent this logic purely in xaml rather than in the code behind?

My layout:

```
<Grid>
<Grid/>
<GridSplitter/>
</Grid>
<Button/>
```

Comment: Mike how do you purpose to trigger the OnClicked Event in XAML without the use of Event Handlers..??

Comment: As mentioned, if you want pure XAML you'll have to avoid the clicked event handler.  How about a checkbox instead of a button?  You won't have to manually implement logic to toggle a boolean property and you can bind directly to the `IsChecked` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind the `Visibility` dependency property of your `Grid` to a boolean property in the `DataContext` (which should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)) and use a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx):

```
private bool _isGridVisible;
public bool IsGridVisible
{
    get { return _isGridVisible; }
    set
    {
        if (_isGridVisible != value)
            return;
        _isGridVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsGridVisible"); // This can sometimes be named RaisePropertyChanged
    }
}

private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsGridVisible = !IsGridVisible;
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsGridVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
    <!-- stuff -->
</Grid>
```

***How to set button content:***

*IValueConverter:*

```
public class MyBooleanToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? ">>" : "<<";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

<Button Click="OnClick" Content="{Binding IsGridVisible, Converter={StaticResource MyBooleanToStringConverter}}"/>
```

*Style:*

```
<Button Click="OnClick">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="<<"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGridVisible}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value=">>"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how will I change the content of the button on click?

Comment: There are a few ways: Bind the `Content` property to a string that is changed in the same way as the bool; Bind the `Content` property to the same bool and convert it to a string using an `IValueConverter`; Use a `Style` with `DataTriggers` that sets the `Content` property of the button.